# How to avoid duplication of code when using two constructors in a class C#

Tags: c#, .net

Hi All I have two request DTOs, of which one is the parent and one is the child.

```
    public class PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    [Required]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("currency")]
    public string Currency { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("supplierid")]
    [Required]
    public string SupplierId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("accountid")]
    [Required]
    public long AccountId { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest: PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest
{
    [JsonProperty("merchantCode")]
    [Required]
    public string MerchantCode { get; set; }
}
```

There are two types of payment request one which the Merchant Code is required and one where the merchant code is not required. Depending on the request I have another class that uses two constructors to handle the data passed into the request.

```
    private readonly string _merchantCode;
    private readonly string _installationId;
    private readonly string _version;
    private readonly string _paymentMethodMaskCode;
    private readonly string _orderDescription;
    private readonly long _amount;
    private readonly string _currency;
    private readonly string _email;
    private const byte Exponent = 2;
    private readonly string _orderCode;

        public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest paymentRequest)
    {
        _amount = (long)(paymentRequest.Amount * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, Exponent));
        _orderDescription = paymentRequest.Description;
        _currency = paymentRequest.Currency;
        _orderCode = $"{paymentRequest.AccountId}_{DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}";
        _merchantCode = paymentRequest.MerchantCode;
    }

    public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest paymentRequest, string email, WorldPayMerchantConfig config)
    {
        _amount = (long)(paymentRequest.Amount * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, Exponent));
        _orderDescription = paymentRequest.Description;
        _currency = paymentRequest.Currency;
        _orderCode = $"{paymentRequest.AccountId}_{DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}";
        _email = email;
        _merchantCode = config.MerchantCode;
        _installationId = config.InstallationId;
        _version = config.Version;
        _paymentMethodMaskCode = config.PaymentMethodMaskCode;
    }
```

The problem is as you can see in the code I am duplicating the initialising of certain local variables in both constructors.

```
        _amount = (long)(paymentRequest.Amount * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, Exponent));
        _orderDescription = paymentRequest.Description;
        _currency = paymentRequest.Currency;
        _orderCode = $"{paymentRequest.AccountId}_{DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}";
```

Does anyone have a cleaner way of doing this?
I have tried using constructor inheritance for the second constructor as shown below.

```
       public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest paymentRequest)
    {
        _amount = (long)(paymentRequest.Amount * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, Exponent));
        _orderDescription = paymentRequest.Description;
        _currency = paymentRequest.Currency;
        _orderCode = $"{paymentRequest.AccountId}_{DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}";
        _merchantCode = paymentRequest.MerchantCode;
    }

    public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest paymentRequest, string email, WorldPayMerchantConfig config) : this(paymentRequest)
    {
        _email = email;
        _merchantCode = config.MerchantCode;
        _installationId = config.InstallationId;
        _version = config.Version;
        _paymentMethodMaskCode = config.PaymentMethodMaskCode;
    }
```

But this does not work as using `: this(paymentRequest)` throws a conversion error as it cannot convert from PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest to PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest.
Any Ideas?

Comment: Build an interface for PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest and use it instead

Comment: Alternatives: create a common base class and accept that as the input, or create a static method to convert from `PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest ` to `PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest` and use `this(ConversionMethod(paymentRequest))`, or create an implicit cast operator onoverload on one of the two types to convert from one to the other.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar can you please shown an example by pasting an answer of the implicit cast operator. Do you mean `: this((PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest)paymentRequest)`

Comment: Essentially something like that, but your example uses an explicit cast operator. Would you like to go with that approach? If so, I can provide an answer.

Comment: Question: Why don't you use nullable values and just check them in the ctor? You wouldn't need a second ctor that way..?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar which ever way is the cleanest implicit or explicit. I would have thought Explicit is cleaner?

Comment: @MaikHasler I cant use nullable values because some of the Variable cant be null depending on the request

Comment: *as you can see in the code I am duplicating the initialising of certain local variables in both constructors.* I haven't fully read but I think you might want to use Virtual, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual

Comment: I missed that the lite request is derived from the fat request type. I don't 100% understand why this question exists now, since the lite request is already assignable to the fat request type. You just have the `:this` on the wrong constructor.

Answer (score 2):

**Using constructors only.**

The simplest way to do this is to call `: this` from different constructor (as `PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest` inherits `PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest`, not vice versa), but you need to handle other params in second constructor and change your code a bit:

```
public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest paymentRequest) : this(paymentRequest, null, null)
{
    _merchantCode = paymentRequest.MerchantCode;
}

public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest paymentRequest, string email, WorldPayMerchantConfig config)
{
    _amount = (long)(paymentRequest.Amount * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, Exponent));
    _orderDescription = paymentRequest.Description;
    _currency = paymentRequest.Currency;
    _orderCode = $"{paymentRequest.AccountId}_{DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}";

    _email = email;

    if (config != null)
    {
        _merchantCode = config.MerchantCode;
        _installationId = config.InstallationId;
        _version = config.Version;
        _paymentMethodMaskCode = config.PaymentMethodMaskCode;
    }
}
```

Or another approach - you can create non-public constructor to initialize common data and call it from public ones (the code is cleaner (my opinion) than in approach above and you have separate place to initialize common properties without `null`s and `if`s):

```
// protected (only for common data) and PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest as parameter
protected GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest paymentRequest) 
{
    _amount = (long)(paymentRequest.Amount * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, Exponent));
    _orderDescription = paymentRequest.Description;
    _currency = paymentRequest.Currency;
    _orderCode = $"{paymentRequest.AccountId}_{DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}";
}

public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest paymentRequest) : this((PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest)paymentRequest)
{
    _merchantCode = paymentRequest.MerchantCode;
}

public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest paymentRequest, string email, WorldPayMerchantConfig config) : this(paymentRequest)
{
    _email = email;
    _merchantCode = config.MerchantCode;
    _installationId = config.InstallationId;
    _version = config.Version;
    _paymentMethodMaskCode = config.PaymentMethodMaskCode;
}
```

**Using separate method.**

You can create separate method which will contain logic which is same for both types:

```
private void InitializeCommonData(PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest paymentRequest)
{
    _amount = (long)(paymentRequest.Amount * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, Exponent));
    _orderDescription = paymentRequest.Description;
    _currency = paymentRequest.Currency;
    _orderCode = $"{paymentRequest.AccountId}_{DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}";
}
```

Then you can initialize properties/fields:

```
public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest paymentRequest)
{
    this.InitializeCommonData(paymentRequest);
    _merchantCode = paymentRequest.MerchantCode;
}

public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest paymentRequest, string email, WorldPayMerchantConfig config)
{
    this.InitializeCommonData(paymentRequest);
    _email = email;
    _merchantCode = config.MerchantCode;
    _installationId = config.InstallationId;
    _version = config.Version;
    _paymentMethodMaskCode = config.PaymentMethodMaskCode;
}
```

Comment: Not OP, but I prefer your constructor approach here because it still allows readonly fields/properties to be set. [Redacted part where I missed that `PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest` is derived from `PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest`]

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar `This does make the assumption that PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest is derived from or implicitly castable to PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest` - it is in question - `PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest` inherits `PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest`, so it should be fine (at least for OP case).

Comment: Somehow I missed that, and now I'm confused as to why OP is asking the question. :D

Comment: Yes I think I like the constructor way here too. Thanks @DiplomacyNotWar for your help but I think I like this answer. I wish I could give 2 ticks

Comment: Wait @Roman the constructor way does not work. The issue is when I use the `: this(paymentrequest)` on the first public constructor, I get an error saying cannot call itself. its like the protected constructor is not being picked up as the base constructor. Could that be because its protected?

Comment: @user17603119, your're right, see edited answer, added casting - `this((PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest)paymentRequest)`

Comment: Well then is it not less lines of code if I just scrap the protected constructor and put a explicit cast like this ` : this((PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest)paymentRequest)` on the second public constructor?

Comment: @user17603119 You can't do that because `PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest` doesn't inherit from`PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest`. You could just move the `this (paymentRequest)` to the first constructor, since `PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest` inherits from `PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest`.

Comment: @user17603119, well, you can't just delete protected constructor as it contains only common data (to avoid duplication). You can try the approach suggested by @DiplomacyNotWar to use `: this` on different constructor (in question), but you need to pass some value for `email` and `config`. If passing some defaults is OK for you then you can go with that. But as for me it shouldn't be done because you'll have incorrect object state (it is the reason the second constructor is added) just for code reuse

Comment: @Roman I am confused now. So are you saying its best to just use the constructor one you have posted above? Has it been edited correctly to deal with the inheritance of the two DTO classes

Comment: @user17603119, not really. I just say it is possible way to use almost same code as you posted just move `:this` to first constructor (and passing additional args). I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @user17603119, see edit

Answer (score 0):

You can pass always the base class and invoke always to your complete constructor:

```
    public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest paymentRequest)
        : this(paymentRequest, null, null)
    {
    }

    public GemPayPaymentRequestBuilder(PaymentSupplierPaymentRequest paymentRequest, string email, WorldPayMerchantConfig config)
    {
        _amount = (long)(paymentRequest.Amount * (decimal)Math.Pow(10, Exponent));
        _orderDescription = paymentRequest.Description;
        _currency = paymentRequest.Currency;
        _orderCode = $"{paymentRequest.AccountId}_{DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks}";
            
        _email = email;

        var liteRequest = paymentRequest as PaymentSupplierLitePaymentRequest;
        if (liteRequest != null)
        {
            _merchantCode = liteRequest.MerchantCode;
        }
        else if (config != null)
        {
            _merchantCode = config.MerchantCode;
        }

        if (config != null)
        {
            _installationId = config.InstallationId;
            _version = config.Version;
            _paymentMethodMaskCode = config.PaymentMethodMaskCode;
        }
    }
}
```

In the complete constructor (the constructor that manage all possible parameters) you can try cast your class. If the class is Lite, you set it's properties.